# Excel VBA: Faster way of finding the column letter of a header?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code for finding the column letter of a given header:

```
Public Function GetColumnLetter(ByRef in_cells As Range, ByVal column_header As String, Optional look_at As Excel.XlLookAt = xlPart) As String
    GetColumnLetter = Split(in_cells.Find(what:=column_header, LookAt:=look_at, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False), "$")(0)
End Function
```

But it seems to be a little slow.  It seems to take a few seconds on some worksheets when it seems like it shouldn't take more than a second.  I have to do this for a number of different columns in a number of different worksheets.

Is there a faster way of doing this?

EDIT: I just made a helper function that calls this function, but w/just the first row (`in_cells.Range("1:1)`), and also changed `xlByRows` to `xlByColumns`, and this has sped things enough.

Comment: Does in_cells refer to the entire table or just the header row?? If it refers to the entire table, combine that with xlByRows search order and you are searching too big an area.

Comment: It appears extremely fast if *in_cells* is restricted to a single row.

Comment: I didn't bother to restrict it to just the one row because I figured that by searching by rows it should return pretty quickly from looking in the first row, so usually it's just the range of the entire worksheet.

Comment: What is the purpose of column_header ?

Comment: `column_header` is the header of the column being sought.

Comment: Pretty sure you have that backwards. I think xlByRows steps through each row in column A then each row in Column B, etc.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff Oh, hmm, that makes sense.  I'll have to try that when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, here is an extremely fast function that does what you want without invoking `Find`. According to my (very old) notes, it came from [here](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/05/21/column-numbers-to-letters/). The parameter `c` represents the index of the column in question, as in the property `Selection.Column`.

```
Public Function GetColumnLetter(ByVal c As Long) As String

    Dim p As Long

    While c
        p = 1 + (c - 1) Mod 26
        c = (c - p) \ 26
        GetColumnLetter = Chr$(64 + p) & GetColumnLetter
    Wend

End Function
```

**EDIT**: Given clarifications in comments, here is a setup for testing `.Find` vs `.Match`, which appears to be faster. Using the variant values of the array [might be faster still](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/), but I'll leave it here.

Set up a first row of data:

```
Public Sub MakeUglyFirstRow()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim i As Long, p As Long
    Dim strChar As String
    Dim initialLength As Integer

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
    initialLength = 5
    For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
        p = 1 + (i - 1) Mod 26
        strChar = String(initialLength, Chr$(64 + p))
        rng.Cells(i).Value = strChar
        If i Mod 26 = 0 Then initialLength = initialLength + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

The original function (plus error handling for a value not found), and a match version calling the function above:

```
Public Function GetColumnLetter_ByFind(ByRef in_cells As Range, ByVal column_header As String, Optional look_at As Excel.XlLookAt = xlPart) As String
    Dim rngFound As Excel.Range
    Set rngFound = in_cells.Find(what:=column_header, LookAt:=look_at, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    If Not (rngFound Is Nothing) Then
        GetColumnLetter_ByFind = Split(rngFound.Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False), "$")(0)
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetColumnLetter_ByMatch(in_cells As Range, text_to_find As String, Optional look_at As Excel.XlLookAt = XlLookAt.xlPart) As String
On Error Resume Next
    Dim rngFirstRow As Excel.Range
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim col As Long
    Dim r As Long

    Set rngFirstRow = in_cells.Rows(1)
    col = 0

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        If look_at = xlPart Then
            result = .Match("*" + text_to_find + "*", rngFirstRow, 0)
        Else
            result = .Match(text_to_find, rngFirstRow, 0)
        End If
        If .IsError(result) = False Then
            col = CLng(result) 'will need an offset if the range's first column is not 1
        End If
    End With

    If col > 0 Then
        GetColumnLetter_ByMatch = GetColumnLetter(col)
    End If
End Function
```

The (very crude) test method (some parameter explanation below):

```
Public Sub Test_ColumnFinding(Optional testString As String = "yyy", _
                              Optional numberOfTests As Long = 1000, _
                              Optional printResults As Boolean = True, _
                              Optional printEvery As Integer = 10)

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim timStart1 As Single, timEnd1 As Single, timTotal1 As Single
    Dim timStart2 As Single, timEnd2 As Single, timTotal2 As Single
    Dim strTest1 As String, strTest2 As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
    For i = 1 To numberOfTests
        timStart1 = Timer
        strTest1 = GetColumnLetter_ByFind(rng, testString, IIf(i Mod 3 = 0, XlLookAt.xlPart, XlLookAt.xlWhole))
        timEnd1 = Timer
        timTotal1 = timTotal1 + (timEnd1 - timStart1)

        timStart2 = Timer
        strTest2 = GetColumnLetter_ByMatch(rng, testString, IIf(i Mod 3 = 0, XlLookAt.xlPart, XlLookAt.xlWhole))
        timEnd2 = Timer
        timTotal2 = timTotal2 + (timEnd2 - timStart2)
        If printResults Then
            If i Mod printEvery = 0 Then
                Debug.Print i, "GetColumnLetter_ByFind", strTest1, timEnd1 - timStart1
                Debug.Print i, "GetColumnLetter_ByMatch", strTest2, timEnd2 - timStart2
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print "GetColumnLetter_ByFind took " & timTotal1 / numberOfTests & " seconds on avg to execute"
    Debug.Print "GetColumnLetter_ByMatch took " & timTotal2 / numberOfTests & " seconds on avg to execute"

End Sub
```

Where `testString` controls distance to match, `numberOfTests` the repetition, `printResults` whether or not to see debug output, and `printEvery` how often to check in on that output.

My results, for 1000 tests but no result debug output:

```
GetColumnLetter_ByFind took 0.003546875 seconds on avg to execute
GetColumnLetter_ByMatch took 0.00134375 seconds on avg to execute
```

Comment: The reason for the find is because I'm looking for very particular strings within the headers.  I don't have indices for them.

Comment: @supercheetah I see, can you give a specific example of what you are trying to find, and how the header relates?

Comment: The header line (the first line) has all the labels for all the columns, so I might be looking for a column such as "Serial Number", and I can't be certain as to which column number or letter that would be.

Comment: @supercheetah I think if you clarified the intent with an edit of the OP you might get some better ideas. Are you looking for substrings of cell values, or only entire strings? Are you only searching in row 1, or in any designated first-row-of-range? Does case matter? What will you do with the letter output? (Obviously, you're satisfied at the moment, so I'm just asking for posterity, I guess.)

Comment: In my code, I put in optional parameters for searching substrings or whole strings (the `look_at` parameter), and this is just passed on to `Find()`.  Most of the time it's just one row, and usually the first, but not all the time.  And the letter output is used for a number of different things, and I can't pin it down to just one single use-case.

Comment: @supercheetah Yes sorry, I overlooked that parameter for some reason. A fuller answer now available above.